# How can i put into kafka Producer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

producer.send() accepting 2 parameters one is kafka topic and 2nd is generated output.How can we make kafkaproducer.py using below scripts.***

Kindly help me to merge both python into single file so that we can use for this script to push the data into kafka topic.

```
import time
from kafka import KafkaProducer
kafka_bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'
kafka_topic_name = 'test1topic'
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_bootstrap_servers,value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
producer.send(kafka_topic_name, script_output)
```

Comment: What is the problem that You have?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you can't add code to the `KafkaProducer`, but you can wrap it as new producer, and makes it get a code, or just add to the `Generator` object a kafka producer and make the `start` function send the data thru kafka

Comment: can you send me the full code, because i have not all things what could do.. but still not working..

Comment: @AnjaliRao Im not going to write this code, just add the producer to your generator object, and makes the start function send the output

Answer (score 0):

You just pass it from the output of your generator function

For example, don't use it one file, use proper Python best practices of importing your own modules

```
from somescript import generate_data

for data in generate_data():
    producer.send(kafka_topic_name, data)
```

Rather than having the generator just print data, it should yield the data, thus returning a Python generator object

Otherwise, you would replace the print statement in the Generator class with `producer.send`, like you've already shown

Comment: I need count of available unique drivers I'd, timestamp and on_duty variable . I tried to call but giving errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means